# hovering table of contents and changing element's backround-color in pdf

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, colors, hyperlink, table-of-contents

I want the following thing in Microsoft Word. If I hover the table of contents or figures or a hyperlink (after I have converted that as .pdf file not in word), the element's background-color will change. Now, it appears only a hand when hovering in  the pdf file. In addition how can I change the color? I want sth like that.

[image]
 Is it required customization in pdf?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that this can be done only in browser (hellow backgroung when hovering) and not in Adobe reader. See more [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111934/getting-yellow-background-color-on-link)